# how to make a jerking in a sprite motion

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

all, I am making a game in which a sprite is move from one position to another through a jerk of 19 pixel, basically I want to make a game just like stacker online. in the app store, in this game the box is move through a jerk of 19 piexel , and the object is moving is in the grid , i have following code but I not give me the jerk motion

```
-(void)actionLayer
{ 
isRunning = 0;

addPixedlValue += 19;
id  actionMove = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:6 position:ccp( 50,109)];  //300,100


id actionMoveDone = [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(LayerAction:)];

animateAction  = [CCSequence actions:actionMove, actionMoveDone, nil];


NSLog(@"pixel value %d",addPixedlValue);



[boxSprite runAction:animateAction];    

}


 -(void)LayerAction:(id)sender
{
addPixedlValue +=19;
id  actionMove = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:6 position:ccp( 270,109)];  //300,100


id actionMoveDone = [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self  selector:@selector(actionLayer)];

animateAction  = [CCSequence actions:actionMove, actionMoveDone, nil];

[boxSprite runAction:animateAction];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem can be sort out By scheduling a selector for a time interval say 0.1 and you can update the position according to your self.

```
-(void)moveSprite
{
   sprite.position = ccp ( sprite.position.x + 5 , sprite.position.y); 
}
```

And unshedule the selector whenever needed to stop the sprite.

For Scheduling a selector

```
[self schedule : @selector ( moveSprite ) interval : 0.1];
```

For unscheduling

```
[self unschedule : @selector ( moveSprite )];
```

This help you in make jerking movement.

Comment: if you want to start moving the sprite as the scene load you can use [self schedule : @selector ( moveSprite ) interval : 0.1]; in init method or if you want to use it on some action then you should add this code to action selector.

Comment: thnx, I want to insert a boundary.. any idea about this, that through this axis the brick will move in that boundry

Comment: I want to insert a boundry thorugh which my sprite will move in that direction

Comment: can you give me your email address so that if any problem occur I will contact with you through email